# How to use Oracle ODP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, dll

I need to know if i am sayng true:

1.I have installed on client machine oracle 11.xxx client and i can install **anyone** of odp.net version to connect from .net to oracle database

2 Other way to use odp.net is to put

- oci.dll
- ociw32.dll
- Oracle.DataAccess.dll
- orannzsbb11.dll
- oraocci11.dll
- oraociicus11.dll
- OraOps11w.dll

into application directory (which has reference to Oracle.DataAccess.dll). This way i **dont have to** install odp.net yes?

Comment: When I installed the oracle client the Oracle.DataAccess.dll file was one of the files installed. I wouldn't try any short cuts with Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you are right though 2nd option looks better as you may need not to install oracle on PROD machine while deploying you application.